# After-update trigger gets 'bad bind variable' error

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-update

When trying to make a trigger in Oracle which updates table `PAND` after changing `AFGEVINKT` from 0 to 1 in table `BGT_PAND_MUTATIE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AU_BGT_PAND_MUTATIE
AFTER UPDATE OF AFGEVINKT ON BGT_PAND_MUTATIE 
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

   UPDATE PAND
   SET VRIJNUMMER1 = NULL  
   WHERE PAND.ID =: BGT_PAND_MUTATIE.ID;

END;
```

I get the following message:

```
Error(5,20): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'BGT_PAND_MUTATIE.ID'
```

Table `BGT_PAND_MUTATIE` has columns `ID` and `AFGEVINKT`. Table `PAND` has columns `ID` and `VRIJNUMMER1`.

What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have:

```
WHERE PAND.ID =: BGT_PAND_MUTATIE.ID;
```

The colon in the `=:` is making the following identifier be treated as a bind variable. You don't refer to the table directly though; you use [the `NEW` psdeudorecord](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E):

```
WHERE PAND.ID = :NEW.ID;
```